# Android Email Application Source Code

Tags: android, email, android-source

I was wondering if we could get hold of the Androids Native Email Application Source Code..

If so please point out to the link.

Thank you

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Harsha,

The source code can be found here: https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_email

Edit: Link updated (2020/08/24): https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_packages_apps_email

Comment: The link in Mr. Tate's answer is now dead, is there an updated location?

Comment: @JohnRobinson Updated.  Thanks for the notice.

Comment: How did you import it? After cloning, some of the classes are missing,

Comment: @WillTate Can we clone the app, change the package name, and publish? What will say google play market?